# How to add a SAML assertion to a SOAP security header in Spring using Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, soap, saml, spring-ws

I have a requirement to pass a SAML assertion as a token inside a SOAP security header. I am using Spring-WS as the framework.

The XML that I want to create looks like this:

I have a requirement to pass a SAML assertion as a token inside a SOAP security header.

The XML that I want to create looks as below. As can be seen, the XML contains the assertion with the `wsse:Security` block.

Is there a way to do this with the `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` class ?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

            <Assertion MinorVersion="1" MajorVersion="1" Issuer="http://www.bea.com/saml"
                       IssueInstant="2005-11-10T11:27:36.233Z" AssertionID="HRMC-SM172.26.5.143.1106860829320"
                       xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
                <Conditions NotOnOrAfter="2005-11-10T15:27:36.233Z" NotBefore="2005-11-10T11:22:36.233Z"/>
                <AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:unspecified"
                                         AuthenticationInstant="2005-11-10T11:27:36.233Z">
                    <Subject>
                        <NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">ANYAGENT
                        </NameIdentifier>
                        <SubjectConfirmation>
                            <ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:sender-vouches</ConfirmationMethod>
                        </SubjectConfirmation>
                    </Subject>
                </AuthenticationStatement>
            </Assertion>

        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:DPSretrieve xmlns:m="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dps">
            <m:version>1</m:version>
            <m:vendorID>your 4 digit vendorID</m:vendorID>
            <m:service>PAYE</m:service>
            <m:entityType>EmpRef</m:entityType>
            <m:entity>as advised by SDS Team</m:entity>
            <m:dataType>P6</m:dataType>
            <m:got>0</m:got>
            <m:nItems>0</m:nItems>
        </m:DPSretrieve>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: I ended up doing it according to the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it via this answer, which worked perfectly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666667/3094805